# Ruby on rails. Sort a hash by number of endorsements to display in a chart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, hash, charts

I've made a statstics page on which i display a chart with users and number of endorsements they have, which looks like this:
[image]

What I want to do now, is to sort the displayed result by the number of endorsements, and not sure how to properly do that.

The @data I am displaying is built like this:

```
@data = @users.map { |user|
            amount = user.inbound_endorsements.joins(:endorsed_user).group(:name).count
              if !amount.empty?
                {name: user.name, data: amount}
              end
            }
```

And in my view,

```
<%= @data.compact %>
```

Gives a hash like this:

> [{:name=>"Jess Corwin", :data=>{"Jess Corwin"=>1}}, {:name=>"Rhiannon
>   Nicolas", :data=>{"Rhiannon Nicolas"=>1}}, {:name=>"Assunta Pfeffer",
>   :data=>{"Assunta Pfeffer"=>2}}, {:name=>"Rafaela Farrell",
>   :data=>{"Rafaela Farrell"=>1}}, {:name=>"Maurine Hettinger",
>   :data=>{"Maurine Hettinger"=>1}}]

And I want to sort it by the number.

I've tried diffeerent approaches like:

```
<%= @data.compact.sort! %>
<%= @data.compact.sort_by{ |name,data| data } %>
<%= @data.compact.sort_by{ |d| d[:data] } %>
```

and other similiar approaches, most of them result in an error:

> comparison of Hash with Hash failed

Any help on how can I accomplish this will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr.sort_by { |h| h[:data].values }
=> [{:name=>"Jess Corwin", :data=>{"Jess Corwin"=>1}}, 
    {:name=>"Rhiannon Nicolas", :data=>{"Rhiannon Nicolas"=>1}},        
    {:name=>"Rafaela Farrell", :data=>{"Rafaela Farrell"=>1}}, 
    {:name=>"Maurine Hettinger", :data=>{"Maurine Hettinger"=>1}},
    {:name=>"Assunta Pfeffer", :data=>{"Assunta Pfeffer"=>2}}]
```

Comment: Great! Now only if you could tell me how to reverse the order, make it descending :)

Comment: @Helban, `arr.sort_by { |h| h[:data].values }.reverse`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Thats exactly what i was looking for. Quick and great answer, thanks!